# select fails in custom model codeigniter 2

Tags: codeigniter, select, model

I have a problem with database select function, in my custom model. This is the code

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('inflector');
    }

    public function fetch($parameters = array(), $raw = FALSE)
    {
        $tablename = $this->getTableName();

        $this->select_fields(FALSE == empty($parameters['fields']) ? $parameters['fields'] : FALSE);
        unset($parameters['fields']);

        if (FALSE == empty($parameters['limit'])) $limit = $parameters['limit'];
        if (FALSE == empty($parameters['offset'])) $offset = $parameters['offset']; else $offset = 0;

        unset($parameters['limit']);
        unset($parameters['offset']);

        if (FALSE == empty($limit))
        {
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        }

        $this->parseFilters($parameters);

        $query = $this->db->get($tablename);

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            if ($raw)
                return $query;

            $rows = $query->result();
            $objects = array();
            foreach ($rows as $row)
                $objects[] = $this->hidrate($row);

            return $objects;
        }
        else
        {
            return array();
        }
    }

    protected function select_fields($fields)
    {
        if (TRUE == empty($fields))
        {
            $fields = "`" . $this->getTableName() . "`.*";
        }
        $this->db->select($fields);
    }

    public function fetchOne($parameters = array())
    {
        $parameters['limit'] = 1;
        $list = $this->fetch($parameters);

        if (FALSE == empty($list))
        {
            return reset($list);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Expecifict in  `$this->db->select($fields);
Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on a non-object`

The model is a custom model and the applicacions model  extends of this model. The question is why throws that error the database is correct.

I have  a MY_loader create in codeginiter 1.7 and I try update to codeigniter 2

```
  class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader
  {
function model($model, $name = '', $db_conn = FALSE)
{       
    if (is_array($model))
    {
        foreach($model as $babe)
        {
            $this->model($babe);    
        }
        return;
    }

    if ($model == '')
    {
        return;
    }

    if ( substr($model, -4) == '_dao' )
    {
        return parent::model('dao/' . $model, $name, $db_conn);
    }

    parent::model( 'dao/' . $model . '_dao', $model, $db_conn);
    include_once APPPATH . '/models/' . $model . EXT;
}
  }
```

I don't know how update this model to codeigniter 2 and I believe this Loader generates error with my MY_Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try troubleshooting why does db return as a non-object.

I'd remove all code and start with a simple select(), if that works, I'll start adding code gradually and see where it breaks.

everything *seems* to be in order but first you'll need to see if the basic functionality exists.

so
1)remove all code, see if a basic select() works, if it doesn't, troubleshoot further.
2)if it does, keep adding code and see what breaks the select() statement.
3)keep adding code until you spot the issue.

Comment: I hava do that and nothing. The probllem is the database command like select() trows this: Fatal error: Call to a member function select(). I have a Model in aplicación/core/  It is a custom model and I don't know why the model not charge the database commands

Comment: So to be clear, Even with an empty model, The $this->db->select() method throws a fatal error? 

I've just wrote some basic code on my end that verified that it's not the case.

Create a simple method in MY_Model called test, have it return true.
then try activating that method, if it works, add a simple select statement in it and work from there.

Comment: Thanks Patrick the problema is I try update the codeigniter 1.7 to 2 and I have a MY_loader.php and MY_Model Those are in codeigniter 1.7 and I try update to Codeigniter 2 the MY_Loader extends for CI_Loader but have a function model